# Are both the "future perfect" and "future perfect continuous" used in everyday conversations?

Tags: word-usage, tenses, future

I would like to know if native English speakers use these tenses in daily conversations. Or, perhaps, it's mostly used as formally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Or, perhaps, it's mostly used in formal speech"

Answer (score 2):

Well, not exactly daily, because it isn't all that often that you need to talk about things from that temporal perspective (looking back from the future). But they're perfectly normal parts of conversation, formal or informal.

Informal examples:

> By the time you get there I'll probably have finished!
>
> I'll have been sorting out boxes all day, so I think I'll be ready for a drink.

Answer (score 1):

The infrequent use of the future perfect, and even more so in progressive/continuous form, rests not so much with register as with the relative infrequency of the situations requiring it: an event or resultant state viewed as completed at some point in the future, especially when the *time* of completion is more topical than the completion itself:

> a.) I will have finished the report by Friday afternoon.
>   b.) I will have the report finished by Friday afternoon.
>
> c.) I‘ll have finished cleaning out the garage in time to take them to the airport.
>   d.) I’ll be finished cleaning out the garage in time to take them to the airport.

Grammatically, a. and c. are in the future perfect while b. and c. are in the future. In a. and c. the time — deadline or subsequent action — is more topical while in b. and d. it is having performed the action, though ideally, deadline and completion are coterminous. The choice rests, of course, with the speaker. A [Google Books NGram](https://books.google.de/books?id=QgTgPc14-IgC&pg=PA410&dq=%22will+have+made+it%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi665DukufbAhXNyaQKHTiuDOUQ6AEIJDAA) shows about an equal distribution for sentences similar to a. and b.

> c.) By the time he parks the car, the concert will have already started.
>   d.) You forgot/have forgotten to pick them up at the airport; they will have been waiting for hours now.

There is really no other way to express c. other than the future perfect, and since parking spots near concert or other entertainment venues are difficult to find, it is a frequently uttered sentence indeed. In d., however, the speaker’s “now” is the present and the act of waiting is not completed, but still ongoing: the classic example of a situation calling for the present perfect. Another way to express the same thought is:

> e.) You forgot/have forgotten to pick them up at the airport. They’ve *probably* been waiting for hours now.

While in e. the speaker is reasonably certain they are still waiting, they may have given up and taken public transportation into town and whiled away the hours with a meal and drinks.

Especially in written, more formal contexts, what looks like the future perfect is used to indicate probability in the past — in this case, the *very* distant past:

> This *will have been* especially true as far as meateating is concerned since improved tool-using [*will have made*](https://books.google.de/books?id=QgTgPc14-IgC&pg=PA410&dq=%22will+have+made+it%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi665DukufbAhXNyaQKHTiuDOUQ6AEIJDAA) it increasingly easy to deal with the mechanics of capturing prey, penetrating the skin and removing the meat from larger animals, etc. — Francis Clark Howell, François Bourlière , eds., *African Ecology and Human Evolution*, 2008, 410.

Since there are no prehistoric records of toolmaking beyond the tools themselves, the writer chooses to couch a statement about their advantages in the future + perfect to indicate strong probability in the past. While one occasionally hears this usage in spoken English, the tendency would be to use as in e. past simple and an adverb.

Comment: Those four utterances are typical usage. What actual proof do you have? These questions like so many others are just a matter of opinion.....

Answer (score 0):

**It's rare to talk about future activities not that but 5-10pc is obvious. Although it depends on you and the situation**

let's take example with verb "make"

> **Future perfect**
>
> I will have made ( pp ) my all ________(whatever you want to make)
>
> **Future perfect continuous**
>
> I will have been making ( pp + continuous ) ________(whatever you want to make)

Answer (score 0):

Very common usage in "everyday speech" are uses with the idea of ""by then"":

- Don't worry. **I'll have done it by then**. By four o'clock. By tonight. etc. etc.
- Come on, man, I won't have finished by six o'clock.

Whenever there is a "by then", a time in the future, it is very common.

- No, John, I don't want to do that [go out for a drink] because **I'll have been working** for 15 hours straight then. [by that time]

Those are very common uses in everyday speech. We don't even realize we're using them much of the time. They are not formal at all.